Could or would? Past regular practice or possibilities?
I have some difficulties in understanding the difference between “could” and “would” in the text below.

When I was a child, we used to go out together for cultural activities,
once a month. We would [not could] visit museums and art galleries, or we
would [not could] go to a concert, the theatre and the like. It’s true that
making choices did not always come easily to us. Some of us were fond
of music, while the others could be quite indifferent to it. But we
were learning to make courageous compromises and always managed to
find something appropriate that would meet all our demands. Sometimes
after that we would [not could] go to a nice small restaurant, where we
could sit and share our impressions while enjoying good food.

I know that “[w]hile "would" indicates things from the past that were a regular practice or habit (eg "when I was young I would go the beach"), "could" indicates possibilities - things that were possible, available to you” (Astralbee). So “could” means that someone was able to do something, but we don’t know whether they actually did it or not.
Based on this reasoning, if our family did all of the named activities in the past, I should use "would" everywhere in this text. But my English teacher said to me that in some sentences I'd better use “could”. It puzzles me a little.
For example, if I say

while the others could be quite indifferent to it,

I do mean that on some occasions the others were indifferent to it. In my view, I should use “would”, because I don’t speak about the possibility here, but about how they actually were (they were indifferent).
Idem in the phrase:

where we could sit and share our impressions while enjoying good food.

We actually did sit there and did enjoy good food. So it was not only possible, but it also happened. Why shouldn’t it be “would” here?
I also wonder whether I can replace "could" with "might" in the phrase:

while the others could (might?) be quite indifferent to it.

I understand that I'm asking too many questions, but I really need your help. So I would really appreciate it if you could clarify these issues.
Thank you so much in advance!

You could just as well say 'others were indifferent to it' if they were habitually uninterested in music.  In your second example, could implies had the opportunity to.
